# Algorithm to Encrypt in Objective-C and Decrypt in Java

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, encryption

Want to know algorithm (if exists) that will match the results in both Objective-C and Java.

Objective:
Ojective-C will send the encrypted data and need to validate with the details that are encrypted in Java.

So need the common algorithm where encryption output value is same.

i.e. EncryptionInObjectiveC(NSString *) = EncryptionInJava(String);

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Data is data, regardless of what language you're coding in. Any encryption algorithm that does the same thing in both languages would work.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you convert data to Base64 and then apply an encryption algorithm. Have a look at Apple's [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008019-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Comment: Why would you convert the data to Base64 before encrypting?